# How can I extract information about SSL encryption on a particular domain

Tags: security, http, ssl

When I am entering any https website I can view information about it's certificate and the encryption suite it is using. For example using if I go to google, I will get something like this: [image]

Is there a way to get this information (that it is using AES Galois counter mode and elliptic curve Diffie Hellman ephemeral) programmably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most SSL libraries give you the informationen, e.g. in Perl

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;
my $sock = IO::Socket::SSL->new( .. ); # connect + ssl upgrade
print $sock->get_cipher; # smthg like RC4-SHA, ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA...
```

of course, the agreed cipher depends on the suite of ciphers the client itself offers to the server, which are different between browser/OS and different between SSL libraries.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean like [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) or with cli openssl, like below? (please note: the openssl-output often depends on the version used locally; an old version delivers a bad result)

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443

CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3728 bytes and written 446 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: DB556CAAB8C35CEC6645BD7EE94F93942DBB1BA7D8605436508F6E41ECC23AD4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 5EBFF88F2B23F077342C40A1FCF5C2576E113411019CB8A010F70DA55C8FE54F5FEFBFB1C7B2738E20341A4C3E17A3AA
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
```